# How to send multiple documents using RMongo

Tags: json, r, mongodb, rjson, rmongo

I am following the conventions from   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/
to send a batch of multiple documents in one call of RMongo::dbInsertDocument.

```
data=data.frame(A=c(1,2),B=c(3,4))  
L=lapply(split(data,rownames(data)),as.list)  
names(L)=NULL  
dataJSON = toJSON(L)  
cat(dataJSON)
```

which gives the following result:

```
[  
 {  
  "A":1,
  "B":3
 },
 {
  "A":2,
  "B":4
 }
]
```

Then

```
dbInsertDocument(rmongo.object=myRmongo.object, collection=myCollection, doc=dataJSON)
```

returns the following error:

```
Error in ls(envir = envir, all.names = private) :  
invalid 'envir' argument
```

Note that if I replace

```
L = L[[1]
```

Then

```
cat(dataJSON)
```

gives the following result:

```
{  
 "A":1,
 "B":3
}
```

and the same call to dbInsertDocument works with no error (and the data is indeed sent to the database)

Comment: What is the error output? Can you print out your ``dataJSON`` so we can inspect it?

Comment: @tommychheng I have detailed my question

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone figured this out? I would really like a better way to do this, but for now am just looping over the list (not ideal)

```
data=data.frame(A=c(1,2),B=c(3,4))  
L=lapply(split(data,rownames(data)),as.list)  
names(L)=NULL  
for (i in 1:NROW(L)) {
    dataJSON = toJSON(L[[i]])  
    output <- dbInsertDocument(mongo, "test_data7", dataJSON)
}
```

Comment: FYI I have filed an issue on RMongo's github: https://github.com/tc/RMongo/issues/22