# How do you bulk insert documents in MongoDB from R?

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb, rmongo

I have a dataframe in R and I am trying to bulk insert each row of the dataframe as separate document in MongoDB. The closest I could do is using following script which creates a document and makes the rows of dataframe as its sub document.

```
x <- toJSON(unname(split(score, 1:nrow(score))))
bson <- mongo.bson.from.JSON(x)
mongo.insert(mongo,'abc.abc',x)
```

On the other hand, I want each row as separate document. I also see that above method is very fast but if we loop around the rows, it would highly reduce the speed

Comment: I have already posted the same question (but for `Rmongo` instead of `rmongodb`) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564321/how-to-send-multiple-documents-using-rmongo. Also I have put a github issue on this https://github.com/tc/RMongo/issues/22

Comment: I see that the question was asked in 2013. Has there been no solution to this since then?

Answer (score 9):

The new `mongolite` package does this automatically:

```
library(mongolite)
m <- mongo("iris")
m$insert(iris)
```

Comment: WOW, mongolite is awesome!

Comment: If you are looking for a way to create a MongoDB collection from an R dataframe, look no farther than mongolite.  You basically create a collection object then run methods on it, like 'insert' in Jeroen's example.  Super simple and fast. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(rmongodb)
df <- data.frame(A=c("a","a","b","b"), B=c("X","X","Y","Z"), C=c(1,2,3,4), 
stringsAsFactors = F) 
lst <- split(df, rownames(df))
bson_lst <- lapply(lst, mongo.bson.from.list)
mongo.insert.batch(mongo = mongo, ns = "db.collection", lst = bson_lst)
```

And please, dont't use `mongo.bson.from.JSON`, use `mongo.bson.from.list` instead. It is much more straighforward (and much more faster!) way to convert R object to bson object.

Comment: Thank You very much. That's exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I cannot upvote your answer as it requires some minimum reputation which I don't possess right now :D

Comment: you are welcome. pls close this question if you satisfied with answer.